# Object of class Codeception\Maybe could not be converted to int

Tags: codeception

I'm checking out Codeception, and I'm trying to write my own grabber.

In my WebHelper.php:

```
function grabMaxOffers() 
{
    return 10;
}
```

(note:  eventually, this will return a dynamic value)

In my TestCept.php file:

```
$max = $I->grabMaxOffers();
$I->wantToTest("Maximum offers ($max)");
```

There error I always get is:

> PHP Notice:  Object of class Codeception\Maybe could not be converted to int in tests/acceptance/TestCept.php on line 21

What am I missing? I wrote two other grabbers (returning strings) that worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not pass parameters into `wantTo`. wantTo is test name, nothing more. That's why test is failing.
2. Codeception uses `Maybe` proxy object while analyzing the test. It mocks strings, array, or anything else. But it should be implicitly converted to string with `(string)$max`.
3. Probably you wanted to use comments, and not `wantTo` statement. You should try `amGoingTo` method.

Cheers